# Facing problems with shell scripts in installing Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I am trying to install Hadoop 2.2.0 on ubuntu -12.04 . Everything was going fine. When I execute /sbin/start-dfs.sh, I am getting the following error message,

```
start-dfs.sh: 82: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: 
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I searched over the internet and found a JIRA issue which is related to it with following URL
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8432

Did anybody face this issue while installing hadoop and does anybody have a solution for my issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are executing start-dfs.sh as sh or some other shell not bash, As Jira discussion suggests, Execute the start-dfs.sh command in bash as follows

```
bash /usr/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```